# Auto generated save excel file name VBA Macro?

Tags: vba, excel

Auto generated excel file name VBA Macro?
Hi all i want auto generated excel file name in macro
my code is below here

```
Sub Sheet_SaveAs()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  With wb
    .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\autogenrate.xlsx"
    '.Close False
  End With
End Sub
```

my code is working fine but when i save next time then asking do you want replace it but i want auto generate name

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want this program to return, as it's not entirely clear from the question and it's vital for understanding your problem.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i want auto generate when i save excel file

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the previous autosaved version or create an additional new autosave?

Comment: i want creating additional new

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix is to change to a unique name each time.  The easiest way to do this might be to use a date-time string

```
Sub Sheet_SaveAs()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  With wb
    .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
            Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & _
            Replace(Format(Now, "Long Time"), ":", "") & _
            ".xlsx"
    .Close False
  End With
End Sub
```

The date and tie part are seperate to allow you to use seconds and therefore your limit is 1 save per second.  If you need more frequent saves you would have to include a millisecond counter too.  The good thing about this method is that it keeps your backups in sequential order in the folder.

You can read more about formatting dates etc. here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx